# How to optimize android application in allocated memory

Tags: android, android-database

I am developing an Android application. In it I use a `SQLiteDatabase`. This database has lots of data, in a way that when I start the application, it is allocation around 85mb of RAM, and that is too much.

I am asking for help optimizing this. Any help is welcomed, pointing to improvements, any visible problem, or even a source to diminish the problem.

As source, check the "Allocated memory in `LogCat` on Android Studio:" [Allocated memory image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4xCf.png)

[image: Allocated memory image]

> Database code:

```
public class DataBase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static String DB_PATH = "";
    private static String DB_NAME = "Dastansara";
    private static int DB_VERSION = 1;
    private SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
    private final Context myContext;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * Takes and keeps a reference of the passed context in order to access to the application assets and resources.
     *
     * @param context
     */
    public DataBase(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17) {
            DB_PATH = context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/databases/";
        } else {
            DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases/";
        }

        this.myContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    }

    /**
     * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own database.
     */
    public void createDataBase() throws IOException {

        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = null;
        if (dbExist) {
            // do nothing - database alerdy exist
        } else {

            sqLiteDatabase = this.getReadableDatabase();
            sqLiteDatabase.close();
            try {
                copyDataBase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new Error("Error copying database");
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the application.
     *
     * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
     */
    public boolean checkDataBase2() {

        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
        try {
            String myPATH = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPATH, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            /// database does't exist yet
        }

        if (checkDB != null) {
            checkDB.close();
        }
        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }

    public boolean checkDataBase() {
        File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH+DB_NAME);
        return dbFile.exists();

    }

    /**
     * Open DataBase
     *
     * @throws SQLException
     */
    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {

        String myPATH = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        sqLiteDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPATH, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    }

    public DataBase writeDataBase() throws android.database.SQLException{

        DataBase dataBase = new DataBase(myContext);
        sqLiteDatabase = dataBase.getWritableDatabase();

        return this;
    }

    /**
     * Close DataBase
     */
    public void closeDataBase() {

        sqLiteDatabase.close();
    }

    /**
     * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the
     * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
     * This is done by transfering bytestream.
     */
    public void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

        //Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
        // Path to the just created empty db
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        //Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(myPath);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            if (length > 0){
                myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
        }
        //Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();
    }


    public Cursor getCat1_Datas(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {

        try {
            String query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_Book WHERE Cat_ID = ?";

            Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(query, new String[] {"1"});

            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }
            return cursor;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Log.e("Data Adapter", "getTestData >>" + e.toString());
            throw e;
        }
    }

    public Cursor getCat2_Datas(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {

        try {
            String query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_Book WHERE Cat_ID = ?";

            Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(query, new String[] {"2"});

            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }
            return cursor;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Log.e("Data Adapter", "getTestData >>" + e.toString());
            throw e;
        }
    }

    public Cursor getCat3_Datas(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {

        try {
            String query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_Book WHERE Cat_ID = ?";

            Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(query, new String[] {"3"});

            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }
            return cursor;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Log.e("Data Adapter", "getTestData >>" + e.toString());
            throw e;
        }
    }

    public Cursor getCat4_Datas(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {

        try {
            String query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_Book WHERE Cat_ID = ?";

            Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(query, new String[] {"4"});

            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }
            return cursor;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Log.e("Data Adapter", "getTestData >>" + e.toString());
            throw e;
        }
    }

    public Cursor getAllCats_Datas(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {

        try {
            String query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_Book";

            Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(query, null);

            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }
            return cursor;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Log.e("Data Adapter", "getTestData >>" + e.toString());
            throw e;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {
        if (sqLiteDatabase != null) {
            sqLiteDatabase.close();
        }
        super.close();
    }
}
```

> First fragment code:

```
public class Cat1_fragment_recycler extends Fragment {

    DataProvider dataProvider;
    DataBase dataBase;
    private SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
    Cursor cursor;
    ListView listView;
    private SuperRecyclerView recycler;
    fragment_RecyclerAdapter adapter;
    SwipeableRecyclerViewTouchListener swipeTouchListener;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler__page,
                container, false);

        adapter = new fragment_RecyclerAdapter(getContext());
        dataBase = new DataBase(getContext());
        sqLiteDatabase = dataBase.getReadableDatabase();
        cursor = dataBase.getAllCats_Datas(sqLiteDatabase);

        recycler = (SuperRecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        //recycler.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        ScaleInAnimationAdapter alphaAdapter = new ScaleInAnimationAdapter(adapter);
        SlideInBottomAnimationAdapter scaleAdapter = new SlideInBottomAnimationAdapter(alphaAdapter);
        scaleAdapter.setInterpolator(new OvershootInterpolator());
        recycler.setAdapter(scaleAdapter);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                String title, id, description, fav, cat_id;
                byte[] image;
                id = cursor.getString(0);
                cat_id = cursor.getString(1);
                title = cursor.getString(2);
                description = cursor.getString(3);
                image = cursor.getBlob(4);
                fav = cursor.getString(5);
                dataProvider = new DataProvider(id,cat_id, title,description, image, fav);
                adapter.add(dataProvider);

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        dataBase.close();

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

> Main activity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private DataBase dataBase;
    private Cat1_frag_AsyncTask task;
    private NavigationView mNaviView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        dataBase = new DataBase(this);
        try {
            dataBase.createDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.main_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        TextView toolbar_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
        toolbar_text.setText(R.string.app_name_fa);
        final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setTitle("");
        actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu_driver);
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        if (navigationView != null) {
            setupDrawerContent(navigationView);
        }

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.main_viewPager);
        if (viewPager != null) {
            setupViewPager(viewPager);
        }

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_tabs);
        if (tabLayout != null) {
            tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        }

        mNaviView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        mNaviView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        //// Navigation Drawer custom font
        Menu menu_mNaviView = mNaviView.getMenu();
        for (int i = 0; i < menu_mNaviView.size(); i++) {
            MenuItem mi = menu_mNaviView.getItem(i);
            applyFontToMenuItem(mi);
        }

    }

    private void applyFontToMenuItem(MenuItem mi) {
        Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/vazir.ttf");
        SpannableString mNewTitle = new SpannableString(mi.getTitle());
        mNewTitle.setSpan(new CodeSaz_CustomTypefaceSpan("", font), 0, mNewTitle.length(), Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
        mi.setTitle(mNewTitle);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main_page, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            case R.id.action_recyclerView:
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Swipe_Recycler.class));
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_recyclerView) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, Recycler_Page.class));
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        Main_frag_adapter mainFragAdapter = new Main_frag_adapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mainFragAdapter.addFragment(new Cat1_fragment_recycler(), "آموزنده");
        mainFragAdapter.addFragment(new Cat1_fragment_recycler(), "عاشقانه");
        mainFragAdapter.addFragment(new Cat1_fragment_recycler(), "بزرگان");
        mainFragAdapter.addFragment(new Cat1_fragment_recycler(), "متفرقه");

        viewPager.setAdapter(mainFragAdapter);
    }

    private void setupDrawerContent(NavigationView navigationView) {
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
                new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                        menuItem.setChecked(true);
                        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                        return true;
                    }
                });
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
    private void forceRTLIfSupported() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            getWindow().getDecorView().setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
        }
    }
}
```

**How to set down in Allocated memory ?** please help me and say me optimized way for use database in application. tnx all <3

**Attention :** Please See this code and say me where is my problem?! please don't give me negative point to me,please help me!

Comment: is your database is 85mb or its taking 85mb ?

Comment: @SagarNayak, no my database is 600 kb, application taking 85mb when running start application!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some obvious problems with your code, but maybe you should investigate more in case of eliminating problem.

use [Singleton Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) for your `DataBase` class because creating `DataBase` objects are expensive.

close your cursors when you are done with them. don't leave your cursors open.
actually there is no need to close your database, you can create an instance using your application `Context` (not your activity `Context`) and use that in your application's life time, but I think you should close your `Cursor`s when you are done.

there are some other optimization, such as you can use just one object of `TypeFace` class instead of creating one for each item of your menu.

I see that you are using byte arrays for storing images, because I don't know how you are using them, I can't be sure, but I guess you'll have some troubles with them, maybe you can paste your adapter code.

last thing is you can use [Eclipse MAT](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/) and [LeakCanary](https://github.com/square/leakcanary) to detect your memory leaks.